# Partition mounted but files not visible

Tags: arch-linux, partition, ntfs-3g

I have following 3 main partitions in my laptop

1. Arch Linux (Release 2019.10.01) EXT4
2. Windows 10 NTFS
3. Common Drive NTFS

I backed up my data in external hard disk > formatted > installed windows > installed Arch > transferred data from external hard disk to common ntfs drive when I am still booted in Arch.

Then I booted in Windows and now I can't see my data in common drive. However, my common drive capacity shows filled drive.

Next I went back in Arch to check what happened to my files and now I can't even see my files in Arch!!! Even though `df` command was showing me that my common drive is filled 91%. I tried to umount and mount again with `ntfs-3g` but still I am unable to see my files.

I can see partition is filled in both Arch and Windows but I can't see my files (from both file manager and from terminal).

Following is my fstab file

```
# /dev/sda5
UUID=055429ea-d5e7 /            ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/sda2
UUID=9076       /efi        vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/sda7
UUID=23190878-9e6a  none        swap        defaults    0 0

# Windows OS
/dev/sda6 /mnt/os ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

# Windows OS
/dev/sda4 /mnt/windows ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

Following is result of `sudo df -hT`

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev            devtmpfs  5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
run            tmpfs     5.8G  1.6M  5.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4       91G   11G   76G  13% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.8G  225M  5.6G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.8G   60K  5.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/loop1     squashfs  422M  422M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/pycharm-professional/159
/dev/loop0     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/7917
/dev/sda2      vfat       95M   27M   69M  28% /efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.2G  9.1M  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda4      fuseblk   746G  672G   74G  91% /mnt/windows
/dev/sda6      fuseblk    88G   25G   63G  29% /mnt/os
```

Following is the result of `sudo lsblk -no name,fstype`

```
loop0  squashfs
loop1  squashfs
sda    
├─sda1 ntfs
├─sda2 vfat
├─sda3 
├─sda4 ntfs
├─sda5 ext4
├─sda6 ntfs
└─sda7 swap
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how can I get access to my files?

Comment: BTW, you are aware that NTFS support in linux depends on kernel config options and is still considered "experimental", particularly regarding WRITE operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to umount and mount the partition in command line manually.  BTW, check if there are any errors in dmesg.  Can you provide the ouput of "ls -alh"?

Comment: I tried `umount` and `mount` again. But still I can't see my files. [Here](https://pastebin.com/ZizuDMPY) is `ls -alh` result from the common drive.

Comment: @Dexter How did you transfer your files?  Can you try to move some small files to the drive to see if it’s working.

Comment: I used `rsync - ahW` and I can add remove any additional files in the drive.

Comment: @Dexter Try “cp -a”, can you copy one file/directory from the external drive to the partition?  After copying all the files have you run sync?

Comment: I have already copied successfully. In my case copied files are not visible.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem for one *ntfs* partition of my external HD, not solved since a while. I tried *ntfs-3g* as well, but the problem remained unsolved.

Finally I found a computer with Windows OS, and connected the had disk to it. The problematic partition and one other *ntfs* partition were found, but the other *ext4* partitions were not showed. Since the problematic partition could not be opened, I right click on its icon and tried to recover or restore (somthing similar) the partition, after a few clicks the problem solved.